# What does ';;' mean?

Tags: bashrc

What does the meaning of `;;` in this code from `~/bashrc` file?

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Can I use `;;` in other ways? and where?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html and http://linuxcommand.org/ . You are asking basically about bash syntax. ; generally means continue . ;; is the syntax for case statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
          If the ;; operator is used, no subsequent matches are
          attempted after the first pattern match.  Using ;& in  place  of
          ;;  causes  execution  to continue with the list associated with
          the next set of patterns.  Using ;;& in place of ;;  causes  the
          shell  to  test  the next pattern list in the statement, if any,
          and execute any associated list on a successful match.
```

So no, you can't use ";;" elsewhere, it's case-specific syntax in bash scripts. As for the meaning, if you finish each case item with ;;, it will stop after executing the code for the first match. If you use ;& instead, it will execute the first match, then continue looking for other matches, so you could perform multiple match actions.

For additional information see

http://linuxcommand.org/

and

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Answer (score 1):

That is the end of a single item in your case-switch,
see e.g.:
[bash-case-statement](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/)

Answer (score 1):

The double semicolon indicates the end of the case branch. See `help case` command for details.